# Reduce document size in PDF to increase margins

Tags: pdf, margins

I want to reduce the size of the document in PDF so that I can have larger margins. I need this to print sticky notes without covering the original text. I've tried increasing margins, but it didn't help in reducing the size of the page.

**Useful Information:**

- I'm using Adobe 9 Pro.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do what you want using imposition tools for PDF. Basically you do an N-up imposition with columns 1 and rows 1 and then adjust the media settings so that either the content is scaled down by a certain percentage on the imposed pages or the page size is increased to include a margin.

My companies product, [Debenu PDF Aerialist](http://www.debenu.com/products/desktop/debenu-pdf-aerialist/) (a plug-in for Adobe Acrobat), can do this for you. Basically the steps are as I've described above. I've added some screenshots below so that you can see the relevant settings. The plug-in is not free but there is 14 day trial version available.

[image]

[image]